# The view cannot see/defined my models classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display all parking spaces details (Id + name + status) but my view cannot see my models class

The controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ParkingFinder()
{
        var parking = new ParkingDto();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetCompanyParkingById using HttpClient
            int id = 5;
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync($"Parking/GetCompanyParkingById/{id}");

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api
                parking = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<ParkingDto>().Result;
                
            }
        }

        return View(parking);
}
```

Then I want to call 'parking' from 'ParkingDto' class in view here:

```
@using MVC.SmartParkingSystem.Models.ParkingDto;
```

but I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ParkingDto' does not exist in the namespace 'MVC.SmartParkingSystem.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Solution explorer:

[image]

Comment: 1- Can you check your solution explorer and see the ParkingDto is available in Models folder of the same project?
2- You can try typing in @using MVC.SmartParkingSystem.Models.ParkingDto; and let the intelliscense guide you to your model.

Comment: @Workaholic i try let the intelliscense guide me put this doesn't work. it cannot see my models, it see only ErrorViewModel.cs . I edit the question  and add a picture of the solution plz check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use @model rather than @using, thus the problem solved:

```
@model SmartParkingSystem.Entity.ParkingDto;
```